# Getting irrklang - to work in sharpdevelop

Tags: c#, sharpdevelop, irrklang

I have downloaded the irrKlang sound library, and since I'm using C# with sharpdevelop I have:
a) Added a reference to the DLL such that irrKlang.NET4 appears under References in the project tree.
b) Added the statement 'using IrrKlang.NET4;' to my code, which corresponds exactly to one of the example programs provided.

When I try to compile, SD tells me that the type or namespace name NET4 doesn't exist (are you missing an assembly reference).

If I change the using statement to 'using IrrKlang;' as (rather confusingly) appears in another .net example program, my application compiles but I get the runtime error "Error: Could not load file or assembly 'irrKlang.NET4, Version .... or one of it's dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".

What is going on here? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unable to reproduce this with SharpDevelop. I can use IrrKlang and run sample code to play some sounds using the library. Can you provide your project and source code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that assembly was not constructed properly

instead of

using irrKlang.Net4;

change it to

using irrKlang;

and all is well :)

Comment: I have changed it to exactly that and SD says the namespace 'irrKlang' cannot be found ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure why then in Visual Studio I add reference to irrKlang.NET4 and added using irrKlang.NET4 and got error message "the namespace NET4 could not be found are you missian a reference" Once I changed it to using irrKlang;  then it worked and I am able to see all properties and methods of class.  i used irrKlang-1.4.0b.zip

Comment: Argh. Could be SD that's the problem then. How infuriating! Maybe VS is doing something by default that SD doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

IrrKlang comes preloaded with various versions for different .NET distributions - both x32 an x64. Make sure you're using the correct one, also set your target build for the corresponding .NET version you're using... 
And yes, you should be doing :

```
using IrrKlang;
```

.just an idea...